# Fn+F6 & F7 does not work for screen brightness in 12.04

Tags: screen, function-keys

I am using Toshiba Portege R835-P70 and function keys work as expected on Windows but they do not on Ubuntu 12.04. For e.g. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> are supposed to change screen brightness but do not work.

What is the solution for this issue?

I tried adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor“` to `/etc/default/grub`, but it introduces an additional problem in that the laptop wakes up to a faintly visible dark screen from hibernation.

I know this is an old issue, but if it is so common, why isn't there a simple solution to it and why isn't it incorporated in latest versions of Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

open your terminal and type this

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and find a line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and change it to like that. then close the editor and do `sudo update-grub` and give a restart. check it out now.

Comment: I have already tried doing that. Above introduces an additional problem in that the screen boots to very faintly visible dark upon waking up from hibernation.

Answer (score 0):

See a solution that worked on my Protege 705-P35 at [Toshiba Portege Z830\Z835 [Linux Laptop Wiki]](http://www.linlap.com/toshiba_portege_z830-10f). To make the new script executable, type:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/restore_brightness
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The following edit to `/etc/default/grub` helped me:

```
sudo nano `/etc/default/grub`
```

and then change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Then run `update-grub` and reboot.

<sub>[Source](http://www.refreshit.info/2012/08/solved-brightness-increase-and-decrease.html)</sub>

Comment: @snoop: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/231744/revisions)?