# Brightness doesn't decrease on an HP Pavilion G6

Tags: 12.04, brightness, hp-pavilion

I have a **HP Pavilion g6** laptop. After installing Ubuntu, screen brightness does not not decrease. Due to this high brightness, I am unable to use Ubuntu properly.

Graphics- ATI Radeon.

Please help me solve the problem.

Comment: By "does not decrease", do you mean brightness change via fn keys of your laptop or do you mean via Ubuntu's system brightness settings?

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine had the exact same problem on a Samsung NP530 laptop, after an Ubuntu 12.04 kernel update.

`/etc/default/grub`, `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable, he added `acpi_osi=`

After running `update-grub` and a reboot, problem solved.

Similar questions:

[What does the kernel boot parameter "set acpi_osi=Linux" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28848/what-does-the-kernel-boot-parameter-set-acpi-osi-linux-do)

[Screen brightness not changing on Acer 5742 notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21523/screen-brightness-not-changing-on-acer-5742-notebook)

[Brightness controls stopped working after update on a Samsung QX412-S01AU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168197/brightness-controls-stopped-working-after-update-on-a-samsung-qx412-s01au)

[Fn+F6 & F7 does not work for screen brightness in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142350/fnf6-f7-does-not-work-for-screen-brightness-in-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `acpi_backlight=vendor` upon start.  I've had to do that for two laptops, an ASUS and a Dell in order to make the backlight work.

Add to the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`, `acpi_backlight=vendor`.  Then run `update-grub` and reboot.